# How to download files from Marklogic in linux box to windows

Tags: marklogic

I have MarkLogic server on Linux and want to download files on Windows box. As far as I know MarkLogic cannot communicate to multiple environment. But is there a way by which I can download files on different platform?

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are looking to do. Are you trying to expose files on the MarkLogic server's filesystem, or documents stored in the database, or are you looking to initiate the download of a file from the MarkLogic server and save it to the Windows filesystem? Can you update your question with some more details about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Hansen, I am trying to download files from MarkLogic server (in Linux environment) and save it to the Windows filesystem.

Comment: Are you saying that you've got MarkLogic running in Linux and a separate MarkLogic instance running in Windows, and you want to copy files from one MarkLogic to the other? Or are you saying that you want to export content from MarkLogic running in Linux so that the content will be on a Windows file system? Or do you something running on Windows that just wants to do searches or retrieve individual documents from MarkLogic on Linux?

Comment: Hi Dave, I want to do export MarkLogic running in Linux to windows file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic comes with a REST api that allows you to `GET` individual documents via HTTP. For details see:

- http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents

If you are more interested in a bulk export, I'd advice looking into MarkLogic Content Pump:

- https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp

There is also the Client API library that make use of the REST api to allow various tasks, including getting documents. It is available in both Java and NodeJS:

- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/intro#id_49446
- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev

All of the above will work across multiple types of Operating Systems.

HTH!